# What is the map used in navigation or object-tracking applications in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, object, navigation, tracking

I'm quite new to Android. I have to develop an object tracking app. I have already added Google maps to my app and the map is showing up (green-color satellite pics map). But it seems navigation apps use a different looking map and I want to have that map instead of this one I already added.

How to get the Google map used in navigation apps (which is yellowish in color)?

Please check following URLs; I have this: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=10comfn&s=8#.U0qW-PmSyls

I need this: http://i58.tinypic.com/awbx9s_th.png

Here is my code to get the green map:

```
package com.sdg.etspmobileuser;

import com.sdg.etspmobileuser.*;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class TrackObjects extends Activity{
       static final LatLng TutorialsPoint = new LatLng(21 , 57);
   private GoogleMap googleMap;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.track_objects);
      try { 
            if (googleMap == null) {
               googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            }
         googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: Show some code and your `green-color satellite pics map`.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, the solution is pretty simple. Just change this:

```
googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
```

To this:

```
googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
```

Comment: Thanku soo much~it wrked!  ^_^